# JSON.net - Deserialising nested objects to single list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialising a JSON response to C# objects using JSON.net.
I am having issues with converting nested objects to a C# list.
I get the JSON response below. 
I want to put all the nodes under `variants` in a single `List<Variant>` in C#. 
How can I edit my deserialiser so that it can be properly deserialised?

```
{
  "feature_id": "48808",
  "feature_code": "",
  "company_id": "1",
  "feature_type": "S",
  "parent_id": "0",
  "display_on_product": "Y",
  "display_on_catalog": "N",
  "display_on_header": "N",
  "description": "",
  "lang_code": "nl",
  "prefix": "",
  "suffix": "",
  "categories_path": "30,149,161,218,219,220,221,222,483",
  "full_description": "",
  "status": "A",
  "comparison": "Y",
  "position": "8830",
  "purpose": "find_products",
  "feature_style": "text",
  "filter_style": "checkbox",
  "variants": {
    "61719": {
      "variant_id": "61719",
      "variant": "CEE 230V\\/16A",
      "description": "CEE 230V\\/16A",
      "page_title": "",
      "meta_keywords": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "lang_code": "nl",
      "feature_id": "48808",
      "url": "",
      "color": "",
      "position": "0",
      "seo_name": null,
      "seo_path": null,
      "image_pair": null
    },
    "61720": {
      "variant_id": "61720",
      "variant": "CEE 400V\\/16A",
      "description": "CEE 400V\\/16A",
      "page_title": "",
      "meta_keywords": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "lang_code": "nl",
      "feature_id": "48808",
      "url": "",
      "color": "",
      "position": "0",
      "seo_name": null,
      "seo_path": null,
      "image_pair": null
    },
    "61721": {
      "variant_id": "61721",
      "variant": "CEE 400V\\/32A",
      "description": "CEE 400V\\/32A",
      "page_title": "",
      "meta_keywords": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "lang_code": "nl",
      "feature_id": "48808",
      "url": "",
      "color": "",
      "position": "0",
      "seo_name": null,
      "seo_path": null,
      "image_pair": null
    },
    "61722": {
      "variant_id": "61722",
      "variant": "CEE 400V\\/63A",
      "description": "CEE 400V\\/63A",
      "page_title": "",
      "meta_keywords": "",
      "meta_description": "",
      "lang_code": "nl",
      "feature_id": "48808",
      "url": "",
      "color": "",
      "position": "0",
      "seo_name": null,
      "seo_path": null,
      "image_pair": null
    }
  }
}
```

C# class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace CsFeature
{
public partial class Feature
{
    [JsonProperty("feature_id")] public string FeatureId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("feature_code")] public string FeatureCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company_id")] public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("feature_type")] public string FeatureType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent_id")] public string ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_on_product")] public string DisplayOnProduct { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_on_catalog")] public string DisplayOnCatalog { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_on_header")] public string DisplayOnHeader { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")] public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lang_code")] public string LangCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prefix")] public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("suffix")] public string Suffix { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("categories_path")] public string CategoriesPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("full_description")] public string FullDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")] public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("comparison")] public string Comparison { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("position")] public string Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variants")] public List<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    [JsonProperty("variant_id")] public string VariantId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("variant")] public string VariantVariant { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")] public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page_title")] public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("meta_keywords")] public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("meta_description")] public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lang_code")] public string LangCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("feature_id")] public string FeatureId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")] public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("color")] public string Color { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("position")] public string Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("seo_name")] public object SeoName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("seo_path")] public object SeoPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image_pair")] public object ImagePair { get; set; }
}

public partial class Feature
{
    public static Feature FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Feature>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
    {
        errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this Feature self)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }
}

public static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
        Converters =
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter {DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal}
        },
        Error = Feature.HandleDeserializationError
    };
}
}
```

Comment: if might work if you define the variants model as an `IList<string, Variant>` ?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Unfortunately that won't work in my case as when serialising I need it to be a list, not multiple objects.

Comment: I answered your question  , kindly mark my answer as the answer of your question as it solves your problem.  Thank you

Comment: I think you will need to deserialise the variants it in 2 steps to get a list of variants. First to a collection of key value pairs, then convert the Variant values to a list.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy That sounds promising! is there anyway to incorporate that into a custom JsonConvertor so it happens automatically when I call from the deserialisation method?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, Variant>` for your `Variants` property.  That will allow you to handle the numeric keys.  See the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

One approach you could take is to `.Parse()` the JSON into a `dynamic` object.

For example:

```
string jsonString = @"Your JSON String";

dynamic parsedJson = JValue.Parse(jsonString);
```

After that, you should be able to use LINQ to traverse through the `dynamic` object and extract your `Variant`

Sources:

- [T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm)
- [Using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing)

Answer (score -1):

The below code will solve your problem:

- Create the main Class that will keep your `List`:

```
public class JsonList
{
    public List<MainListKeep> ListToKeep { get; set; }
}
```

- Create the Class that defines the type of the items of the `JsonList` class:

```
public class MainListKeep
{
   public string feature_id { get; set; }
   public string feature_code { get; set; }
   public string company_id{ get; set; }
   public string feature_type { get; set; }
   public string parent_id{ get; set; }
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...

   public List<VariantsList> variants{ get; set; }
   
}
```

- Create the Class that defines the type of the items of the `variants`:

```
public class VariantsList 
{
   public string variant_id { get; set; }
   public string variant { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public string page_title { get; set; }
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

And then you deserialize using this:

```
JsonList jsonList = new JsonList(); 
jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonList>(YourJSONContentString);
```

And then you have all of your JSON Response items in the `jsonList` object and you can use them as you want.
The names of the variables that are relevant with your code **must be the same** as you can see above in the classes that I have created.

Comment: See my updated post and the C# class I'm using now, this is the same as what you are trying to do and it results in the Variants list being null after deserialising.

Comment: @Luminai, this happens because  the variants (titles) are  numbers...

Comment: Well yes I know, that is the problem I'm trying to solve. Preferably using a custom JsonConvertor or something like it.